# 'No frame for given id found' in puppetter

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i am using puppetter for web scrapping ;
matchesLinks is an array that contains urls of some games.
my code looks like :

```
for (let i = 0; i < matchesLinks.length; i++) {
   await page.goto(matchesLinks[i]);
   await page.goto(matchesLinks[i]);
   await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 6000));
 }
```

after going to 1 or 2 URL i get error: `originalMessage: 'No frame for given id found'`
anyone can help my why i am getting this error

Comment: Are there more details in the error? Like filename and line number?

Comment: Three lines of code with missing variables isn't enough to reproduce the problem. Which sites are you navigating to? Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: no there is not any other information .
but when i make headless as true it works fine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I have been trying to solve the issue since 3 days now.. no luck at all..
Though the issue disappears completely if you set "headless: true" at browser's launch options.. So this issue is only associated with "headless: false" setting.

For those who try to help. The issue happens when using "page.goto" to access a website that have iframes, and redirect requests (Trying to abort those requests, or waituntil domcontentloaded won't solve the issue if you were wondering). E.g. it happens every time when trying to access "https://www.whatismyip.com/"

Answer (score 2):

You might be facing the issue described here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/7848

You may try to downgrade puppeteer version to 11.0.0 as a workaround

EDIT: The fix has most likely been released. Consider upgrading the puppeteer.